# Is there a way generate a chart on google spreadsheet automatically using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way generate a chart on google spreadsheet automatically using Python? I checked gspread. There seems no api for making charts.

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. There is no way to do this with python.

Google-apps-script can do this, but the spreadsheet-api (Gdata) can't.

You can make a call from Python to Google-apps-script and pass parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much Eddy! Now I have compromised like this: Manually make a chart but leave the data areas blank. Use script to update cells so that the chart can be generated 'automatically'. Seems a few more work to do than what I wanted to achieve but still smart enough to me. I appreciate your help~